# dereference an array of void pointers

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

I have a set of void pointers which I would like to put in an array of void pointers. I start with malloc:

```
void **p2vals=malloc(nelems*sizeof(void*));
```

..which gives me an array of pointers to pointers. But then I want to dereference p2vals like *p2vals which supposedly gets me one void pointer. Of course the compiler doesn't like it but I have a need for it. I want to set

```
*(p2vals+someoffset)=somevoidptr;
```

Comment: "Of course the compiler doesn't like it " ? Meaning?

Comment: And what is the problem?

Comment: What errors/warnings do you have? Could you please elaborate more on your problems?

Comment: How did you dereference it??

Comment: the problem is I can't dereference p2vals with *p2vals. the compiler complains that i dereferenced a void pointer.

Comment: @majidaldosari If the code you have here is accurate, throw away the compiler. `p2vals` is a `void**`, so `*p2vals` (or `p2vals[i]` for `0 <= i < nelems`) is the correct way to obtain the `void*` at the corresponding location. `**p2vals` would be trying to dereference a `void*`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to store memory address as a variable, I suggest you to use `uintptr_t` instead of `void *`.And if you want write or read any offset, just do `(uintptr_t)((char *)(pointer) + offset)`.

Comment: this is the idea that i need.

Answer (score 0):

Consider,

```
int a = 5;
int *p = &a;
```

In this case we indicate to the compiler that p is going to point to an integer. So it is known that when we do something like `*p` , at runtime, the no. of bytes equal to size of an int would be read.

Dereferencing void pointers, the compiler will not understand how many bytes to read exactly. You need to typecast them to some `type` before
 using them